# Master Detail Page Navigation on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I created a Master Detail Page and am tying to implement the part where it navigates to a specific page when one of the side tabs are tapped. However, it keeps going back to the default detail page which is a plain content page.

```
    public class HomePage : MasterDetailPage
{
    string[] sideTabs = { "My Account", "Charity A", "Charity B", "Charity C", "Charity D", "Support", "Logout" };
    ListView listView = new ListView();
    ContentPage master = new ContentPage();
    StackLayout masterStack = new StackLayout();

    public HomePage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this,false);

        //creating content page
        listView.Header = "     ";
        listView.ItemsSource = sideTabs;
        listView.SeparatorColor = Color.Transparent;
        listView.BackgroundColor = Color.Pink;
        masterStack.Children.Add(listView);
        master.Title = "Menu";
        master.Content = masterStack;

        //assigning master detail page properties
        Master = master;
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage ());

        listView.ItemTapped += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Set the BindingContext of the detail page.
            switch (args.Item)
            {
                case "My Account": Detail.BindingContext = new LoginPage (); break;
                default : Detail.BindingContext = args.Item; break;
            }
            // Show the detail page.
            IsPresented = false;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is you are doing it wrong.

A more dynamic way of doing this is using a `class` to hold your `Titles` and `ContentPage` `Types`.

**A class to hold your page data**

```
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    public MasterPageItem(string title, Type targetType)
    {
        Title = title;
        TargetType = targetType;
    }
}
```

**Declare a List of MasterPageItems**

```
public class HomePage : MasterDetailPage
{
    // A Global List of Tabs (ie Pages)
    List<MasterPageItem> Pages = new List<MasterPageItem>();

    ...
```

**Populate your list**

```
public HomePage()
{

    // You need to populate them with a Title and Page Type using typeof()

    Pages.Add(new MasterPageItem("My Account", typeof(LoginPage)));
    Pages.Add(new MasterPageItem("Charity At", typeof(CharityAPage)));
    Pages.Add(new MasterPageItem("Charity B", typeof(CharityBPage)));

    ...
```

You will either have to specify how to link the `Title` to your `Listview` in either xaml or create a `Data Template`

**Example ListView**

```
...

// Here is an example of how you would use a data template in code

var listView = new ListView
    {
        ItemsSource = Pages,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(
            () =>
                {
                    var label = new Label();
                    label.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

                    var viewCell = new ViewCell();
                    viewCell.View = label;

                    return viewCell;
                })
    };

...
```

Now when you subscribe to the `ItemTapped` `Event` the `args` parameter contains a `MasterPageItem`

**ListView.ItemTapped**

```
...

listView.ItemTapped += (sender, args) =>
{
    // you don't really need a switch here, as all your pages 
    // are kept in aa MasterPageItem 

    // Its Good to check if its not null
    if (args is MasterPageItem item)
    {

        // set the Detail page when click
        // Activator.CreateInstance, is just a fancy way of saying create the
        // page from the type you supplied earlier 
        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
        IsPresented = false;
    }
};

...
```

> **Note** : If in doubt always read the documentation

[Master-Detail Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/)

**Additional Resources**

[Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemTapped Event](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemTapped/)

[Data Templates](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/)

[Some more samples](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/)

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal glad to be of assistance